# Regular monomorphisms of commutative rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

What are the [regular monomorphisms](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism) of $\mathsf{CRing}$? Is there a purely algebraic characterization?

Since regular monomorphisms coincide here with effective monomorphisms (see Prop. 1. [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism)), the question is how to characterize those homomorphisms $R \to S$ such that $R \to S \rightrightarrows S \otimes_R S$ is exact. For example, faithfully flat homomorphisms have this property. What about pure homomorphisms?

But these are not the only examples: Every split monomorphism is regular.

Counterexample: Every regular monomorphism, which is an epimorphism, is an isomorphism. It follows that $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is a monomorphism which is not regular.

Comment: It never hurts to recall definitions!

Comment: Martin, I do not know the answer to this. That said, if you are really interested I almost guarantee you that George Bergman (at Berkeley) would at least have a lead. You should shoot him an email.

Comment: @Martin If I understand correctly, pure homomorphisms have the effective descent property for modules, so in particular they are effective epimorphisms. See e.g. [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/16/1/16-01abs.html).

Comment: Follow-up: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2403350/660